# Is multiprocessing.Manager.Queue() thread and process safe?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I am fairly new to multiprocessing in python. I am trying to use Queues to pass messages between processes. As I read through the documentation it says multiprocessing.Queue() is thread and process safe. But it doesn't say whether multiprocessing.Manager.Queue() is thread and process safe. Under the hood it uses native Queue class so I am not sure if it is process safe. Could someone clarify this?

Comment: Yes it is. Manager queue is simply a queue running in another process which you have access to.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Manager` is an RPC mechanism. One side gets a proxy to the object on the other side. You call `my_queue.put(whatever)`, for instance, and the RPC forwards the data to a manager server on the other side that makes the call. The RPC is thread safe and the object on the other side is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

`multiprocessing.Manager.Queue()` is designed to be both thread-safe and process-safe. It is part of the multiprocessing module in Python, which provides support for creating and managing processes, including inter-process communication. The `Queue` provided by Manager is intended to be used in a multi-process environment, and it includes mechanisms to ensure safe communication between processes.

In a multi-process program, each process has its own memory space, and communication between processes typically involves inter-process communication (IPC). The `Manager.Queue()` uses IPC mechanisms to allow different processes to safely exchange data.

It's important to note that if you're working with threads within a single process, you might want to use the regular `queue.Queue` class, as it is optimized for thread safety within a single process. The `multiprocessing.Manager.Queue()` is specifically designed for inter-process communication.